# What's the backslash \" ...\" does here in the rails 3.1.0 and jquery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Here is a function from raislcasts.com complex-form-examples about dynamically adding field to form. The function runs with rails 3.1.3 and jquery.

```
  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)
    end
    link_to_function(name, "add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")")
  end
```

The association is a symbol and has to be. What 's the purpose of `\"...\"` here for `#{..}`? Removing it causes error.

Comment: isn't that to escape the double quotes? the string starts with double quotes, so the nested ones must be escaped so that they don't terminate the string early.

Comment: Of course removing is an error--strings are enclosed by `"` characters; would that be value Ruby code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purpose is to escape quote characters appearing inside the same type of quote characters to make sure that the string does not end with this character

Examples for appropriate usage

```
"This is a \"quote\""
=> This is a "quote"

'This is a \'quote\''
=> This is a 'quote'

"This is a 'quote'"
=> This is a 'quote'    

'This is a "quote"'
=> This is a "quote"
```

Answer (score 3):

Backslash is used to escape the double quote. so that you can use any number of double quotes (prefixed by a backslash) inside the string...

Ex:

```
var test = "Bobby said "Hello!" to the crowd."; 
-> will give you an syntax error 

var test = "Bobby said \"Hello!\" to the crowd."; 
-> double quote for (Hello!) is escaped using backslash
```